# byte[] array varies before and after entering it into SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite

**Why are the two byte arrays different and how do I retain the original byte array without changing it?**

I'm using the Android Camera API to take a picture and I'm attempting to store the byte[] data of the image in SQLiteDatabase and then retrieve it in another activity.
However when I log the byte array as is it given from the camera I get..

```
V/Byte array before db: [B@42a1e7e0
```

Then I insert the byte array (imageData) into the database as well as other variables

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO " + IMAGE_TABLE_NAME +
            " (TIMESTAMP, IMAGEDATA, LAT, LON) VALUES('" + time + "','" + imageData + "','" + lat +"','" + lon +"')";
```

Then I retrieve the byte array back from the Cursor object (images)

```
byte[] imData = images.getBlob(images.getColumnIndex("IMAGEDATA"));

Log.v("byte Array after db", imData + " ");
```

The result of the log is

```
V/byte Array after db: [B@42919440
```

Before you ask there is only one image in the SQLiteDatabase as i've cleared it and tried again.

Comment: Those are memory addresses. You want to compare the actual data. You should try to decode the after byte array to a bitmap and display it. It's probably correct.

Comment: I have tried doing this and the BitmapFactory returns null when decoding the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, this I think is a java fundamental question.

Java is a pass by value language,

The `byte[]` object reference you are creating to retain the image data and the `byte[]` object reference that you use to receive is obviously different. You are printing the hash not the actual byte array. If you look at the byte array they should be the same

Comment: How do I see the actual byte array and not the object reference?

Comment: I thought the byte array might have changed because in the insert command, there is an implicit call to toString() on imageData. Does that not affect the byte array at all?

Answer (score 1):

**FIXED**

The problem was with

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO " + IMAGE_TABLE_NAME +
    " (TIMESTAMP, IMAGEDATA, LAT, LON) VALUES('" + time + "','" + imageData + "','" + lat +"','" + lon +"')";
```

imageData (the byte array) cannot be inserted into the database this way.

I did this

```
dbImages.insert("images", null, createContentValues(imageData));
```

and the function createContentValues(imageData)

```
private ContentValues createContentValues(byte[] image) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("IMAGEDATA", image);
    return cv;
}
```

Going to keep this here for anyone that has this problem in the future, don't insert it using execSQL(string).

Answer (score 0):

You are printing your byte[] data instead of real bitmap. You can get your real bitmap by following function, you just need to pass your byte[] value as argument:

```
    public static Bitmap convertImageByteToBitmap(byte[] byteImage) {

       if (byteImage == null) {
        return null;
       } else {
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteImage);
        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

        return imageBitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: This function returns null, I think BitmapFactory is returning null as it can't decode the byte array

Comment: No, this returns bitmap. I mostly use this function whenever i have work with images. May be problem with byte[] which you pass in this.